# How to calculate cumsum for current row with condition on values of other rows in another column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have dataframe like below:

```
ID Group SubmitDate   BookDate      Amount Total
1     A  2011-01-01   2011-01-01    100    0
2     A  2011-10-01   2011-05-01      0    100
3     B  2012-01-01   2012-02-20    500    0
4     B  2012-02-01   2012-04-01    300    0
5     B  2012-03-01   2012-03-15    400    500
6     B  2012-03-16   2012-03-18    900    900
```

I want to Total for each ID which is equal to sum of Amount for previous rows in the same group if the SubmitDate of current row is after BookDate of previous rows.

i.e For ID 5, SubmitDate of ID  5 is only after BookDate of ID 3 (We look at only IDs in same group), then total  =  500

For ID 6, SubmitDate of ID  6 is only after BookDate of ID 3 and 5 (We look at only IDs in same group), then total  =  500+400 = 900

to regenerate this example

```
data <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
               Group = c("A","A","B","B","B","B"),
               SubmitDate = as.Date(c("2011-01-01","2011-10-01","2012-01-01","2012-02-01","2012-03-01","2012-03-16")),
               BookDate = as.Date(c("2011-01-01","2011-05-01","2012-02-20","2012-04-01","2012-03-15","2012-03-18")),
               Amount = as.numeric(c("100","0","500","300","400","900")))
```

I was thinking of this but it only compares the submital and bookDate of current rows.

```
data %>% group_by(Group) %>% mutate(Total= cumsum( SubmittalDate <BookedDate ) )
```

Comment: shouldnt the total for ID==4 be 0 and for ID==2 be 100?

Comment: @chinsoon12 You are right! I have edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that there is a typo and total for ID==4 be 0 and for ID==2 be 100, and that OP don't mind solution using `data.table` package. Here is an approach:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)
data[, Total :=
    data[data, sum(x.Amount[-.N][x.BookDate[-.N] < i.SubmitDate]), by=.EACHI, on=.(Group)]$V1
]

#   ID Group SubmitDate   BookDate Amount GrpID Total
#1:  1     A 2011-01-01 2011-01-01    100     1     0
#2:  2     A 2011-10-01 2011-05-01      0     2   100
#3:  3     B 2012-01-01 2012-02-20    500     1     0
#4:  4     B 2012-02-01 2012-04-01    300     2     0
#5:  5     B 2012-03-01 2012-03-15    400     3   500
#6:  6     B 2012-03-16 2012-03-18    900     4   900
```

Explanations:

1) `data[data, j=..., by=.EACHI, on=.(Group)]` does a self join using `Group` and performs `j` for each row in `i`. See `?data.table` to understand the meaning of `i`, `j`, `by`, `.EACHI` and `on`. `.` is an alias for `list`.

3) In a `x[i, ...]` join (i.e. x join with i), `x.*` refers to the columns in `x` table on the left of `[`. `x.BookDate[-.N]` takes the BookDate column less the last one, which is the current row.

4) `x.Amount[-.N][x.BookDate[-.N] < i.SubmitDate]` subset and sum the amounts which fulfills OP's requirements.

Comment: Thanks alot. I can not regenerate your solution,. I get this error which I can not figure it out how to fix it                                                    
                                                                                                       
           Error in set(i, j = lc, value = newfactor) : 
  .SD is locked. Updating .SD by reference using := or set are reserved for future use. Use := in j directly. Or use copy(.SD) as a (slow) last resort, until shallow() is exported.

Comment: Can you substitute .SD with data for now ? There is a github issue related with this

Comment: Thank you, it works well. Just wondering how could I make it work if some of BookDate, BookAmt are NULL?

Comment: You can decide how you want to handle them based on your business needs then code that requirement in